# Как скомпилировать программу , заменив определённые значения?

Tags: c++, build

не уверен, что правильно формулирую вопрос.

Допустим, есть программа, в которой используется для запросов определённый ip-адрес из внутренней сети.

```
SOCKADDR_IN address;
address.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr=inet_addr("тут используется этот самый адрес");
```

возможно ли как то изменить программу, чтобы при её компиляции с определёнными параметрами значение ip-адреса менялось само в готовом файле (.exe).

Я даже не могу понять, в какую сторону гуглить. Прошу подсказать, в каком направлении искать информацию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, определенный при компиляции в командной строке макрос.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    printf("%d\n",VALUE);
}
```

Если компилировать в VC++ как

```
cl -DVALUE=256 test.cpp
```

будет программа, выводящая 256. Если

```
cl -DVALUE=123 test.cpp
```

будет выводить 123.

Но не более ли разумно передавать этот параметр, скажем, в командной строке?

Comment: Благодарю. Это был чистый интерес, чтобы знать на будущее , как это реализуется.